# com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix not found

Tags: java, android

> `Required com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix but found com.google.zxing.ByteMatrix.`

But I have added the jar file of `zxing` and also imported `com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix`. Can I resolve this?

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView qr;
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        qr=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qr);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String addr="KowdiarSreevilaslane";
    String name="Aryaputhran";
    String email="gsaryaputhran@gmail.com";
    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
    try{
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(addr+name+email, 
BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);
        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
        Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
        qr.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (WriterException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: The error is shown on   the below line                                                                                      BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(addr+name+email, 
BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);

Comment: how do you import it?

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
```

Or If you want to use any java project ou can use [jar file](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases).

But you have to use ZXing 3.3.2 version.